# What options I should use to rescale video without skewing them in FFMPEG Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ffmpeg, carrierwave

The main issue happens when it processes the recalling

All videos uploading from Apple iOS will process nicely.
But all videos uploading from Android devices are getting skewed.

In my rails app, I am using Carrierwave:Video and FFMPEG to process videos with the help of delayed jobs.

```
class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::Video
  include CarrierWave::Video::Thumbnailer

  # For carrierwave_backgrounder
  include ::CarrierWave::Backgrounder::Delay

  version :rescaled do
    process encode_video: [
      :mp4,
      resolution: "640x480", # Aspect ratio is preserved automatically
      audio_codec: "aac",
      custom: "-strict experimental -q:v 0 -preset slow -g 30",
      callbacks: { after_transcode: :set_success }
    ]
  end


  version :thumb do
    process thumbnail: [{format: 'png', quality: 10, size: 400, strip: true, logger: Rails.logger}]
    def full_filename for_file
      png_name for_file, version_name
    end
  end
```

This is correct videos screenshot

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1D0aNWcVxtL6DbTwBmWWIGzUUuyEyWNOG

This the video screenshot after video process with FFMPEG

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vilExHoan2UuRPH9RbiZig58H1TwyewA

(It's like vertically pressed)

---

Please help me, if you know a solution

Comment: When I use the ffmpeg in the terminal it works nicely. So I thought the issue would be probably with the carrierwave video gem which embedded the ffmpeg methods.

I solved the issue by adding ffmpeg gem separately and using its functionalities separately inside my class. 

and also wrote an article about that..

https://medium.com/@admatbandara/video-upload-processing-with-ruby-on-rails-c3c5aa04e08

Comment: Alright. I'll do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution and here it is...

I required the FFMPEG library separately in the class.

```
require 'streamio-ffmpeg'
```

And the called custom function to do the encoding work.

```
version :rescaled do
 process :encode
end
```

And the ENCODE method will create ffmpeg video object and do the transcode.

```
def encode
  movie = ::FFMPEG::Movie.new(current_path)
  tmp_path = File.join( File.dirname(current_path),   "tmpfile.mp4" )
  options = "[define the options you want]"
  movie.transcode(tmp_path, options)
  File.rename tmp_path, current_path
end
```

This would override the processes from carrierwave and do the encoding with the ffmpeg

That’s all then…

Please mention other solutions if you found any.

Thanks...

Please refer my article for more info:

[Article about this issue and it's background](https://medium.com/@admatbandara/video-upload-processing-with-ruby-on-rails-c3c5aa04e08)